# Why is Trump moving to Florida?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, executive, florida

Donald Trump is moving to Florida. Doesn't he live in the White House in Washington DC? What does it mean that he is moving?

Also, do we know why?

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2019/11/02/us/politics/trump-new-york-florida.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> What does it mean that he is moving?

He changed his permanent residence from Trump Tower in NYC to Mar-a-Lago in Florida, not actually moving. The [change](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/11/01/why-president-trumps-move-from-new-york-to-florida-could-hit-a-wall.html) was made September 27th.

> Also, do we know why?

For *financial, political and legal reasons*.

[The politics behind Trump's move to Florida are crystal clear](https://www.cnn.com/2019/11/01/opinions/trump-move-to-florida-louis/index.html), November 2, 2019.

> Trump has extremely good financial, political and legal reasons to get out of New York: his move is a logical, long-term answer to an immediate set of problems.
>
> The transaction itself is straightforward. Trump will almost certainly continue to own his suite atop Trump Tower, and will continue to move between New York and his Mar-a-Lago resort. But by designating Mar-a-Lago as his domicile -- in legal terms, "his true, fixed, permanent home"-- Trump is announcing he will spend most of each year in Florida (when not in D.C.), making him a resident of the Sunshine State for purposes of voting and paying state taxes.
>
> By doing so, Trump joins a large exodus of New Yorkers who regularly relocate to Florida for the sunny weather and lower taxes.

Florida is considered a [swing state](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swing%20state). Being a resident may give him more votes.

> In 2016, Trump carried Florida's 29 electoral votes over Hillary Clinton by a slim 1.2% margin, only about 113,000 votes out of 9.4 million cast.

...

> The third incentive for Trump to get out of New York is legal. The state Attorney General and the Manhattan District Attorney have launched multiple probes of Trump's businesses, charities, political committees and personal conduct. ...
>
> Those inquiries won't vanish for Trump, simply with his moving away, but he knows that New York's overwhelmingly Democratic officials -- including the state attorney general and Manhattan district attorney -- have no incentive to take it easy on him.

---

[Trump lives in the White House. So, why is he moving to Florida?](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2019/11/01/why-president-donald-trump-moving-new-york-florida/4120843002/), Updated 8:55 a.m. ET Nov. 2, 2019.

> Trump criticized his political opponents in his “Farewell, New York” tweet Thursday suggesting his decision may have had to do with his treatment by political leaders in the city and state.
>
> “Despite the fact that I pay millions of dollars in city, state and local taxes each year,” he tweeted. “I have been treated very badly by the political leaders of both the city and state. Few have been treated worse.”

---

See also [Manhattan district attorney subpoena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_returns_of_Donald_Trump#Manhattan_district_attorney_subpoena).

Comment: Are their requirements for how much time must one spend in FL to declare it to be "a true, fixed, permanent" home. ?

Comment: @BobE - 6 month + 1 day for most people. Those elected to Congress or, now, the president, or serve in the military, must not have any other residence that would be considered permanent.

Comment: Is there a precedent?

Comment: @BobE New York is very aggressive about stopping people from trying to dodge their state taxes by "moving" to another state. I've seen estimates that the state has taken in as much as $1B a year lately by stopping dodgers, which have become more numerous after they capped the state tax deductions on federal taxes. So while "majority of your time" as indicated by Rick is one criterion there are, in fact, many, many others, and a simple time majority need not be sufficient. And the burden falls on Trump to prove he's not a NY resident as dictated by the state of NY, not the other way around.

Comment: @Burt - [Rochester billionaire Tom Golisano changes address to Florida to avoid New York taxes](https://www.syracuse.com/news/2009/05/rochester_billionaire_tom_goli.html)  he says cost him nearly $14,000 a day.

Comment: @user47014 No. Plus, the things that they are presumably investigating (e.g. his businesses) are not moving.

Comment: Does his change in legal address really impact any of the lawsuits/legal investigations against him, other than logistics? Surely none of the cases against him would be dropped or invalidated simply because of his "move" to Florida.

Comment: @Joe - _[A]re not moving_, as far as we know! In the current cases, the investigations are for past practices. Certain changes in the corporate structure would prevent New York from accessing some of his future corporate and tax data. Florida's corporate tax rate is 5.5% versus New York's 6.5%.

Comment: @AnthonyX - Trump considers some high-level New York Democrats to be part of the "witch hunt" against him. It won't change the past (current cases), but may affect the future by preventing them from pursuing further _harassment _.

Comment: @RickSmith Pretty sure it would only hinder a State of New York criminal investigation if Trump Tower were put on wheels and rolled out of the state. Nevermind that most of the investigations of Trump are being run by the U.S. Attorney (e.g. Federal).

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Agree that "principle residence" and "where you spend most time" are not necessarily the same.  I live in Germany, but I work in Switzerland, so I am actually in a flat in Zurich five days a week.  Still a German resident though.

Comment: Is Florida less likely to get his state taxes and release them?

Comment: @user47014 - There is no state income tax, though there are business taxes. The state would have only those tax filings for businesses within the state. Currently that would include two resorts and one hotel, if I recall correctly. There really isn't that much information about the Trump Organization that could be released and, specifically, nothing that would include his personal income. Nonetheless, Republicans generally occupy both the legislative and executive branches; so release of any data is unlikely.

Answer (score -6):

After the lady who built the Mar-a-Lago residence died, she willed it to the government for use as a "winter White House". The US President of the time declined to use it as such, and returned it to the family estate, leading to it eventually being bought by Donald Trump.

After Donald Trump won the US presidency, he decided to put it back to this use for this purpose. As such, it should not be surprising that he would list it as his place of residence.

Comment: Can you please add a reference to support this answer?

Comment: [Wikipedia agrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar-a-Lago)

Comment: wiki quotes NYT July 16, 1981: "On her death in 1973 at age 86, Mrs. Post left the estate to the Federal Government to serve as a winter White House for Presidents and visiting heads of state. But Mar-a-Lago, lying directly in the flight path of the Palm Beach airport, proved too difficult to secure. And as the cost of keeping up the property soared beyond the funds Mrs. Post had provided, the Government returned it to the Post Foundation by an act of Congress that became effective April 1." https://www.nytimes.com/1981/07/16/garden/post-home-for-sale-for-20.html

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the right answer. [January 2017 Trump called](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/821772494864580614) mar-a-lago the winter white house, but it's only just now that he's making it his primary place of residence. This answer doesn't really address op's question about moving, especially just under three years after announcing the winter white house.