# Did Trump vote illegally?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, presidential-election, voter-registration, florida

This may be reaching, and may be inappropriate to Politics, but here goes:

Trump "officially" moved from Trump Tower New York to Mar-A-Lago and therefore cast his vote in the Nov 3rd election as a resident of Florida. However, he had previously signed an agreement that he would not use Mar-A-Lago as his residence (as reported [here](https://thehill.com/homenews/administration/530417-neighbors-stress-trump-cant-live-at-mar-a-lago-after-leaving-white)). Not having any alternative address in Florida (presumably), he could not be considered a Florida resident, thus casting a vote in Florida as he did would be a violation of voting rules, wouldn't it? Again, having previously signed an agreement to not use Mar-A-Lago as a place of residence, and having "converted" the complex from a residence to a club would make the complex ineligible to declare as his residence, and thus make it fraudulent to do so on his voter registration, wouldn't it?

Comment: With whom did he have an agreement not to use Mar-A-Lago as residence?

Comment: I would guess that he'd be in violation of his agreement with Palm Beach, rather than with Florida election law. That is, legally, he did make his residence in Mar-A-Lago, and so he voted legally, but that is a violation of his agreement with Palm Beach, for which they could sue him.

Comment: @divibisan Forgot to mention one other detail (just edited) that the complex was "converted" from a residence to a club some years ago, so wouldn't that lend weight to the argument that he couldn't legitimately declare it as his place of residence?

Comment: @AnthonyX The question is whether Mar-A-Lago cannot be a place of residency under state law (for example, if I tried to call a street corner my residence, it wouldn't be accepted, as a street corner can't legally be a residence) or whether the ban is part of a contract between 2 parties, in which enforcement comes down to one side suing the other.

Comment: @divibisan I understand your point. There is also the matter that I believe the property was reclassified away from residential use according to municipal records/filings. I mention the agreement only as evidence of intent which happens to support the municipal record.

Comment: The city of palm beach has no authority to disenfranchise federal elections. However, they could punish him for living there, using the vote as evidence.

Comment: https://soe.dos.state.fl.us/pdf/guidelinesvoterresidencyupdated_02-2012.pdf is a great reference for this question.

Comment: From your link:  "A number of President Trump’s neighbors in Palm Beach, Fla., are arguing that he is legally barred from taking up primary residence at his Mar-a-Lago resort **after leaving the White House**."  Has Donald Trump left the White House yet????  -1 for an extremely disingenuous question.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but the real answer will likely come down to what qualifies someone to vote in the State of Florida in the USA.  Mar-A-Lago may be a red herring.  Or in this case, would it be an *orange* herring?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket : a "Declaration of Domicile" : https://www.mypalmbeachclerk.com/home/showpublisheddocument?id=1036

Comment: @JustMe why are you claiming that the asker is intentionally asking out of bad faith, which is what you just said when you claimed this was “disingenuous”?

Comment: @Joe I took a look at that document, but I think Florida's state law or a USA Federal law would be the deciding factor as to who could vote (and where).  I'm happily ignorant of both, and hope to keep it that way. ;)

Comment: @JustMe What? You are either being intentionally obtuse or misunderstanding the sentence. Trump will leave the White House, and that sentence claims that he can't live at MaL at that time. Currently, it isn't a problem because he doesn't spend enough time there, but he *also* can't move there *while* President, but they're assuming that won't be relevant until his is no longer President.

Comment: The optimist in me assumes he'll be arrested before spending 21 days in MaL but we'll see

Comment: @JustMe : The "after leaving the White House" part is further clarified in at least some articles by a statement that President Trump is _already_ violating the agreement, but that the other party/parties are not attempting to enforce it out of deference to the office. From an article in the Guardian: "... the town let him get away with breaking rules within the agreement over the last four years because of his role as president." If that clarification were made part of the question, would you retract your allegation of disingenuousness?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> Did Trump vote illegally?

Not based on whether Mar-a-Lago is a residence, even those with no residence can vote. *See*, [Registering and voting in Florida, even if you don’t have a permanent address or ID](https://homelessvoice.org/how-to-vote-in-florida-if-you-are-currently-experiencing-homelessness/).

Thus, the question of whether Mar-a-Lago is or can be a residence for the purpose of voting is irrelevant.

Comment: @Fizz -  The dispute as to whether Mar-a-Lago is a residence is with the City of Palm Beach. Both the State of Florida and Palm Beach County accept that Donald and Melania Trump are citizens and residents, to all intents and purposes. What more can I say?

Comment: Also, "residence" is not the same thing in the very different legal contexts of eligibility for voting and for property restrictions.

Comment: @Fizz "he'd have to have established prior residency in Florida (as that page says)": nowhere on that page does it say anything about prior residence.  There is nothing that says or implies that a homeless person from Chicago cannot turn up at some street corner in Florida and register to vote in Florida using that street corner as a residence address.

Comment: "the question of whether Mar-a-Lago is or can be a residence for the purpose of voting is                                                                                                irrelevant." What about other relevant factors? How did he convince the state that Florida is his "predominant and principal home" when he really lives in D.C.?

Comment: @Jetpack elected federal representatives are an exception - they keep voting based on their "home" jurisdictions. I.e. Obama always voted in Chicago.

Comment: @JonathanReez Right, but Obama's "predominant and principal home" was in Chicago for many years before he was elected.  Trump lived in New York before he was elected in 2016, and voted in New York until 2019.

Comment: @Timbo -  And now he is voting in Florida. _See_, [Why is Trump moving to Florida?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/47328/26455)

Comment: @RickSmith Right... hence this question, of how he is allowed to claim residency without residing there -- without *ever having resided* there. Can an elected official seriously just arbitrarily claim residency anywhere in the country?

Comment: @Timbo - It's not arbitrary, they do need to have a connection to the state and file a document such as a [Declaration of Domicile](http://cdn.cnn.com/cnn/2019/images/10/31/nv_680_22992563_img.pdf).

Comment: @RickSmith: I suppose the question is whether, in this case, that declaration was false in fact.